# Рисование на Python большой разноцветной таблицы или горизонтального графика

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Несколько дней гугления и экспериментов не помогли, прошу совета.
Есть задача вывода таблицы учета рабочего времени сотрудников. Исходные данные (ФИО, дата, количество отработанных часов, требуемое значение количества часов) тянутся из экселя либо рассчитываются путем нехитрых действий (например требуемое значение количества часов учитывает праздничные дни, сокращенные дни, выходные).
На выходе нужна разноцветная таблица/график примерно такого формата:
[image: Пример таблицы]
Ширина таблицы (диапазон дат выборки) может быть очень разным (от нескольких дней до бесконечности, ну до года точно). Конечно за год рисовать такое - будет очень неинформативно, но до месяца будет использоваться точно.
Предварительно задачу визуализации общего количества отработанных часов решал с помощью matplotlib.pyplot.barh, и, в целом, всё устраивало. Но для более детализированного и разноцветного отчета он не подходит.
[image: Пример графика]
Посоветуйте инструмент, с помощью которого можно (если можно) реализовать нужное.
Спасибо

Comment: покажите, что хотите получить и конкретизируйте, почему именно не подходит matplotlib.

Comment: Советую посмотреть в сторону `Plotly` / `Plotly Dash` - это мощная надстройка над matplotlib

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Как я указал - на выходе нужна таблица/график примерно указанного формата. Цветами выделяются ячейки в зависимости от количества отработанных часов (данные значения сравниваются с требуемым значением). Т.е. если человек отработал 8 и должно быть 8 - зеленым, отработал меньше - оранжевым, больше - желтым и т.п. Не в этом суть. В matplotlib не нашел как это сделать. Пытался через застаканный barh, но там несколько другая логика и покрасить как мне надо не получается.

Comment: @MaxU Принял, смотрю. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На поименованные цвета можна посмотреть [здесь](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html).  Каждый бар может быть своего цвета - его просто нужно задать. Осталась небольшая сложность как разметить столбец в зависимости от значения нужным цветом, или поместить в нужную категорию. Решение размещения значений по корзинам есть [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). Соединяем вместе и вот:

```
from bisect import bisect

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

def basket(score,
           breakpoints=[30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
           colours=['red', 'darkorange', 'forestgreen', 'greenyellow', 'gold', 'lavender', 'm']):
    """Assign the basket color depending from value."""
    i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
    return colours[i]


labels = ['Аня', 'Маня', 'Ваня', 'Даня', 'Мишаня', "Андрюха", "Димуха", "HugoBoss"]
values = [25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 89, 40]
colors = [basket(value) for value in values]

# Change the bar colors here
plt.bar(labels, values, color=colors)

plt.ylabel('отработано часов ')
plt.show()
```

результат:

[image: цвет зависит от значения]

Повернуть и навести красоту, думаю, сможете ))
разноцветная таблица называется `heatmap`. [Вот документация](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html). Хотя подумать немного все же придется.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! С хитмапами уже разбираюсь, вот [тут](https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap/) есть разные варианты с реализациями, адаптирую под свои нужды )

Comment: @Юрий, если понравилось, можете даже поднять оценку ответа на единичку... )